# django site framework: Which models should be associated with a site (foreign, manytomany)?

Tags: django, django-models, django-sites

according to the [docu](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/#associating-content-with-a-single-site) this is pretty straight forward:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # ...
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site)
```

but what if i have an additional Model? i.e.:

```
class ArticleAttachment(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="foo/bar")
    # ...
```

ArticleAttachment() is already associated with an Article (which is already associated with a site). should i still add the foreignkey to the site? and if yes/no, why?

(performance is not an issue.)

thx.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the redundant foreign key would only help performance if you want to display all the article attachments with a given `site`, for instance. Otherwise (esp. if you don't care about performance at all), it doesn't really help you, it just introduces more "maintenance" work. You can always access the `site` of an attachment using

```
attachment.article.site
```

and filter using

```
.filter(article__site="...")
```

So if there's no other sophisticated query that only works with this additional database field, I would drop it.